# php: Why we need to set the visibility of class members?

Tags: php, class

I know, by using protected or private, we can limit the visibility of a member in a class. But I'm curious about the purpose of doing so. Calling a class name(`$a = new class B`) doesn't make its members global. So, why still need to protect its members?

Comment: _Calling a class name doesn't make its members global_ Can you brief it up a bit ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a duplicate of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables

Comment: What do you know about [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)?

Comment: "Global" is not the same as "publicly accessible".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For low coupling and high cohesion

Please check below:

> http://www.hokstad.com/why-coupling-is-always-bad-cohesion-vs-coupling